# laravel breeze with react

Tags: laravel, vite, inertiajs, laravel-breeze

Just create a laravel project while using inertia with react.

[image]

Now when ever i run npm run dev i see this

[image]

i have entered both links in the browser, the vite locahost takes me to the laravel + vite page in the first image, while the APP_URL does load any page in my browser

[image]

Comment: You also need to run `php artisan serve` in a terminal window. Are you doing this?

Comment: i show run both npm run dev and php artisan serve

Comment: if you have your own LAMP stack your own web server, then you don't need this. But if you need to test Laravel on your home computer and don't have a server handy, then php artisan serve will start a test web server for you, I believe.